# Sync Disabled for Document Library created with custom list definition

Tags: document-library, list-definition, sync, offline-sync

In our project we are creating custom list definition and list instance based on that definition, as follows:

Elements.XML in List Definition:

```
<ListTemplate
    Name="MyListsDef"
    Type="10000"
    BaseType="1"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="110"
    DisplayName="MyListsDef"
    Description="My List Definition"
    Image="/_layouts/15/images/itdl.png"
    DocumentTemplate="121"/>
```

Lists are created based on that List Definition, during site provisioning, see List Type that matches ListTemplate Type (onet.xml block is below)

<List Title="My Library" Type="10000" FeatureId="{GUID}" Url="Lists/MyLibrary" />

However, when sites are provisioned, those libraries don't have "Sync" option available in the Toolbar and cannot be synced offline, although they have property "EnableOfflineSync" set to TRUE in Advanced List Settings. (When we create Document Libraries based on the OOTB Doc Lib template, they have "Sync" button available in the toolbar.)

What could be the reason for that? Any helpis welcome.

Thanks

Dragan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem recently. I found this blogpost that explains the cause: 
http://srinivasananand.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/sp2013-sync-button-doesnt-appear-for-document-library-created-with-custom-list-definition-2/

and here he has suggested one work around: 
http://srinivasananand.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/sync-button-for-document-library-created-with-custom-list-definition

Hope it helps. 
Sanjay

Comment: Anand (blog author) and me are on the same team. I can confirm his solution is working.

Comment: ahan, I didn't know that :) nice! and thanks

Comment: Very useful post. I just wan to comment for now it's very difficult to me, I have hundred of receivers and other stuff tied to that ID :( ... still any other work around available?